# Insert a combobox inside view in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view page to insert some data.

here is the model:

```
@model BookListMVC.Models.Book
```

I need to insert a combobox linked to another table "Categories".

The compiler does not allow me to insert multiple models because that is probably not the right way.

How I can insert a combobox linked to "Categories" that point to book "IdCategory" ?

Here the actual code full inside:

```
@model BookListMVC.Models.Book

<br />
<h2 class="text-info">@(Model.Id!=0 ? "Edit" : "Create") Book</h2>
<br />

<div class="border container" style="padding:30px;">
    <form method="post">
        @if (Model.Id != 0)
        {
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />}
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Author"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="Author" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Author" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="ISBN"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="ISBN" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="ISBN"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="ISBN" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3 offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">
                    @(Model.Id != 0 ? "Update" : "Create")
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back to List</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the combobox model through **ViewBag** or **ViewData**. For example.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {

        //The data can be obtained from database.
        ViewBag.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{ Text="history", Value="1"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text="literature", Value="2"},
        };

        var model = new Book { Id = 2, Author="author", ISBN="isbn", Name="bookname" };
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is the simple combobox in the view.

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label asp-for="categories"></label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <select asp-for="categories" name="CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories">
                <option>-- select the category --</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="categories" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Model (Categories)

```
public class Categories
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Result
[image]
You can add a property `CategoryId` in model `Book`, even add a property `Categories`.

```
 public class Book
{
    
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    
    public Categories categories { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to pass the object `Categories` to the bakend, you can add a hidden input box and relative javascript.

Add hidden box.

```
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label asp-for="categories"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <select onchange="changeName()" asp-for="categories" name="categories.CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories">
                <option>-- select the category --</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="categories.CategoryName" value="" id="categoryName"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="categories" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Add javascript.

```
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
function changeName() {
    var index = document.getElementById("categories").selectedIndex;
    var text = document.getElementById("categories").options[index].text;
    document.getElementById("categoryName").value=text
}
</script>
}
```

Then you can get all data include Categories and can handling Categories table.

Comment: thank you !! If I have "@model BookListMVC.Models.Book" how I can access to table "Categories" ? C# don't allow me to access to multiple "@model" in the some view.

Comment: Where do you want to access to table `Categories`, in the current view? If you want to access multiple `"@model`, you need to add some indexes on every pameter, about this quesion, you can reopen an issue.

Comment: Please sorry I'am new in MVC, If my model is  "@model BookListMVC.Models.Book"how I can access to "Categories" ? is not clear what is "ViewBag.Categories". I suppose if my model is only  "@model BookListMVC.Models.Book" I can access only to Book and not other tables. Can you please update your response ?

Comment: Every `Book` has a foreign key, you can pass the foreign key to the bakend, then you can deal with  Categories according to the foreign key (CategoryId).